# How to programatically obtain the emulator's model being used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, mobile, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm developing an application to work with many devices and emulators from different resolution, so I have the code to know whether is a real device or emulator, but I'd like to know what emulator (model, type) is being executed to display the application with the correct resolution.

Actually I'm using the code method GetOemInfo() that returns a string with the value "Emulator" or the device's model, with this I just know it's an emulator, not what is.

```
private static string GetOemInfo()
    {
        string oemInfo = new string(' ', 50);
        int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETOEMINFO, 50, oemInfo, 0);
        oemInfo = oemInfo.Substring(0, oemInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
        return oemInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can get the screen size, if that's all you are after.

The most complete method is to use `SystemMetrics`, which has to be P/Invoked from "coredll.dll".

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(SYSTEM_METRICS nIndex);
```

Next, create an enumerated type, like the following:

```
public enum SYSTEM_METRICS : int
{
  SM_CXSCREEN = 0,
  SM_CYSCREEN = 1,
  SM_CXVSCROLL = 2,
  SM_CYHSCROLL = 3,
  SM_CYCAPTION = 4,
  SM_CXBORDER = 5,
  SM_CYBORDER = 6,
  SM_CXDLGFRAME = 7,
  SM_CYDLGFRAME = 8,
  SM_CXICON = 11,
  SM_CYICON = 12,
  SM_CYMENU = 15,
  SM_CXFULLSCREEN = 16,
  SM_CYFULLSCREEN = 17,
  SM_MOUSEPRESENT = 19,
  SM_CYVSCROLL = 20,
  SM_CXHSCROLL = 21,
  SM_DEBUG = 22,
  SM_CXDOUBLECLK = 36,
  SM_CYDOUBLECLK = 37,
  SM_CXICONSPACING = 38,
  SM_CYICONSPACING = 39,
  SM_CXEDGE = 45,
  SM_CYEDGE = 46,
  SM_CXSMICON = 49,
  SM_CYSMICON = 50,
  SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN = 76,
  SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN = 77,
  SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN = 78,
  SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN = 79,
  SM_CMONITORS = 80,
  SM_SAMEDISPLAYFORMAT = 81,
  SM_CXFIXEDFRAME = 7,
  SM_CYFIXEDFRAME = 8
}
```

With this framework all set, you can simply get the width, for example, as follows:

```
int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SYSTEM_METRICS.SM_CXSCREEN);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Screen X-res is {0}", screenWidth));
```

If you want to be lazy, the simple solution would be to simply read the Width and Height of your main form when your project has loaded up.

Of course, if all you are doing is reading the Width and Height before adjusting your form, there will obviously be some flicker on the screen.

Comment: Thanks @jp2code, it works, That's why I needed, not by laziness :) but by the simplicity of the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The emulators don't specifically have any "OEM info" that give you what you're after.  You'll have to deduce it by checking the OS version, screen resolution and possibly even the availability of some APIs (if you're looking at differentiating Pro versus Standard targets).

Comment: Thanks for answering @ctacke, do you know what I can use for checking the screen resolution or similar stuff?

Answer (score 0):

If screen size is not all you are after, here is a method I use to get the info for the device. It reads some data from the registry and some data from... well, you'll see.

```
private static string getName() {
  string name = null;
  using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Ident", true)) {
    var name = key.GetValue("Name", [Unnamed]) as string;
  }
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
    name = getDeviceID();
  }
  return name;
}
```

So, now you need my `getDeviceID()`. Ugh. OK.

```
private const string COREDLL = "coredll.dll";
[DllImport(COREDLL)]
private static extern bool KernelIoControl(Int32 IoControlCode, IntPtr InputBuffer, Int32 InputBufferSize, byte[] OutputBuffer, Int32 OutputBufferSize, ref Int32 BytesReturned);

private static string getDeviceID() {
  // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446562.aspx
  byte[] data = new byte[256];
  Int32 OutputBufferSize = data.Length;
  Int32 BytesReturned = 0;
  // Call KernelIoControl passing the previously defined IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID parameter
  // We don’t need to pass any input buffers to this call
  // so InputBuffer and InputBufferSize are set to their null values
  bool retVal = KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID, IntPtr.Zero, 0, data, OutputBufferSize, ref BytesReturned);
  // If the request failed, exit the method now
  if (retVal) {
    // Examine the OutputBuffer byte array to find the start of the 
    // Preset ID and Platform ID, as well as the size of the PlatformID. 
    // PresetIDOffset – The number of bytes the preset ID is offset from the beginning of the structure
    // PlatformIDOffset - The number of bytes the platform ID is offset from the beginning of the structure
    // PlatformIDSize - The number of bytes used to store the platform ID
    // Use BitConverter.ToInt32() to convert from byte[] to int
    Int32 PresetIDOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
    Int32 PlatformIDOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0xc);
    Int32 PlatformIDSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0x10);

    // Convert the Preset ID segments into a string so they can be 
    // displayed easily.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X8}-{1:X4}-{2:X4}-{3:X4}-",
         BitConverter.ToInt32(data, PresetIDOffset),
         BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 4),
         BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 6),
         BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 8)));

    // Break the Platform ID down into 2-digit hexadecimal numbers
    // and append them to the Preset ID. This will result in a 
    // string-formatted Device ID
    for (int i = PlatformIDOffset; i < PlatformIDOffset + PlatformIDSize; i++) {
      sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", data[i]));
    }
    // return the Device ID string
    return sb.ToString();
  }
  return null;
}
```